# error 404 Sending value to controller in Hosting CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

I have a problem sending value to controller, there is a double on rsport23.000webhostapp.com
https://rsport23.000webhostapp.com/rsport23.000webhostapp.com/pesanan/tambah_form/2
[image]

what should I change?

```
<p><a href="<?php echo site_url('pesanan/tambah_form/'.$value->id_barang); ?>">PESAN SEKARANG
          </a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use with base_url. always work for me.

```
<p><a href="<?php echo base_url().'pesanan/tambah_form/'.$value->id_barang; ?>">PESAN SEKARANG
          </a></p>
```

Comment: I done try but it remains the same double : https://rsport23.000webhostapp.com/rsport23.000webhostapp.com/pesanan/tambah_form/2

Comment: check your config

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the base url in the **application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://rsport23.000webhostapp.com/";
```

then after that you can do like that:

```
<p>
    <a href='<?php echo base_url("pesanan/tambah_form/$value->id_barang"); ?>'>PESAN SEKARANG</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I done try but it remains the same double : https://rsport23.000webhostapp.com/rsport23.000webhostapp.com/pesanan/tambah_form/2